# Find best specified range within sequence of numbers

Tags: calculus, statistics

What is the best formula to find the most popular 'spread' within a sequence with a set range available.

E.g I have 100 numbers and I have to find the most popular 'range' of 10, but the range/band cannot be spread out.

So for a smaller example below I have:

3
1
2
1
2
1
3
4
1
1
1
2
1

And the range needs to be 5, so the range in this example would be 21341 as it totals 11, more than any other range.

Comment: It's just linear search. Slide your range across the sequence and find which has/have the highest sum.

Answer (score 1):

Ideas:

Probably, @ParclyTaxel is right that a brute-force scan of the possible
intervals is an efficient, if slightly boring way to do it. Suppose observations are integers, the smallest observation is above 0 and the largest is below 100. Check how many outcomes are in each interval: 1 through 10, 2 through 11, ..., 91 through 100.
A program wouldn't be difficult to write.

Perhaps a more interesting way is to look at a kernel density estimator of
the data, find what it judges to be the 'mode' and start your search there.

If data are roughly $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=50, \sigma=1),$ then maybe the
highest concentration is around 50. I've included a histogram and tick marks
for each observation in case they provide additional visual clues. (Program in R statistical software.)

```
set.seed(228)
x = rnorm(100, 50, 10)
hist(x, prob=T, main="")
lines(density(x), lwd=2, col="darkgreen")
abline(h=0, col="blue2", main="")
rug(x)
```

[image]

Yes, it seems best to search intervals of width 10 around 50.

If data are from $\mathsf{Gamma}(shape = 5, rate=1/3)$ then maybe
look in the vicinity of $\frac{5-1}{1/3}= 12.$

```
set.seed(229)
x = rgamma(100, 5, 1/3)
hist(x, prob=T, main="")
lines(density(x), lwd=2, col="darkgreen")
abline(h=0, col="blue2", main="")
rug(x)
```

[image]

You can find the mode of the density estimator without looking at a graph:

```
den.inf = density(x)
den.inf$x[den.inf$y==max(den.inf$y)]
## 12.01986
```

Oh, wow! Lucky again.  Of course, if you don't know the distribution ahead of time,
you won't be able to make informed guesses, but you can still use the density-estimation method
to know where to search.

I don't know if your Question is a theoretical exercise, a computer assignment,
or a serious practical issue about finding concentrations of observations in big data. If
the latter, then maybe looking at density estimators is better than scanning
intervals of length 10 and counting.

*References:* For more about kernel density estimators, see the Wikipedia article,
and maybe B. Silverman's book referenced there. Also, [this page](http://adereth.github.io/blog/2014/10/12/silvermans-mode-detection-method-explained/).